# Drain alignment problems

Tags: shower, drains

I have a drain coming out of a cement slab which does not align with the shower drain. It is about 3/4 inch out of alignment and won't flex enough to align them.  How can I attached the shower to the drain?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to chip out the floor & there's a trap beneath so everything's good that way. Then, you can try an Offset Shower Drain. If that doesn't do it then I think your only option would be to use a black rubber flexible (hub-less) coupling.

[image: offset flex]